# How to solve ‘error in derived variable in SPSS'?

Tags: spss

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb3Jg.jpg)

When I do 'overlay scatter plot', I face an error "Error in derived variable Variable13' defined as:constant(variable x variable y)。

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow! In order for us to help you we would need more information. Please edit your post to add the syntax that caused the error, and a sample of your data. Best If you can recreate the problem on a small set of data and share it here, so we can re-create the problem ourselves and find the solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.